# undefined method `model_name' for Net::HTTPBadRequest:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, request, httprequest, venmo

Trying to make a Post Request to Venmo for payment processing in my Rails site.

Here's the form I have in my index.html.erb:

```
<!-- Venmo box -->
                    <div class="box box-warning">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <%= form_tag make_payment_path do %>
                            <%= hidden_field_tag "access_token", @access_token %>
                          <h3 class="box-title">Pay Bill using Venmo Account</h3>
                            <div id="payment_note_input">
                            <%= text_field_tag "payment_note", nil, class:"form-control", placeholder: "add a note to your payment" %>
                            </div>
                            <div id="payment_target_input">
                                <%= text_field_tag "payment_target", nil, class:"form-control", placeholder: "pay an email address" %>
                            </div>
                            <div id="payment_amount_input">
                                <%= text_field_tag "payment_amount", nil, class:"form-control", placeholder: "enter the payment amount!"%>
                            </div>
                                </br>
                        <%= submit_tag "Make payment", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
```

And here's what I have in the make_payment_path method in my controller:

```
def index
if !params[:access_token].nil?
    flash[:success] = "Venmo successfully authenticated!"
end
end

def make_payment_path
if !params[:access_token].nil?

    uri = URI.parse("https://api.venmo.com/v1/payments")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({"access_token" => params[:access_token], "email" => params[:payment_target],
     "amount" => params[:payment_amount], "note" => params[:payment_note]} )

    response = http.request(request)
 end
end

helper_method :make_payment_path
```

I keep getting the error in the title of this post: "undefined method `model_name' for Net::HTTPBadRequest:Class"

I can't seem to find any other similar results to this error. It comes up in the Ruby docs as 308 Permanent Redirect - in draft. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Post your `index` method of your controller.

Comment: Added the index method.

Comment: Whats your model class name?

Comment: For this portion, just User

Comment: ok.Just change your `form_tag` to `<%= form_tag(/'make_payment_path') do %>` and tell me it worked or not.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I tried this with  `<%= form_tag('/make_payment_path') do %> `  (with the forward slash in the quotes) and it gives me "No route matches [POST] "/make_payment_path"